# How to give ListBox items meaningful names

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have populated a listBox with items of type:

```
Tuple<List<Point>,List<int>>
```

Now when I run my application the listBox window display items like so:

```
(System.Collection.Generic.List'1[System.Drawing.Point].Systen,Collection...)
(System.Collection.Generic.List'1[System.Drawing.Point].Systen,Collection...)
(System.Collection.Generic.List'1[System.Drawing.Point].Systen,Collection...)
```

Instead I want listBox to display each item with string "Region" + item's index.

Like so:

> Region0
>
> Region1
>
> Region2
>
> ...

To populate the listBox I use the following code:

```
 listBoxPossibleCandidates.DataSource = possibleCandidates;
```

And possibleCandidates are populated like this with a loop:

```
possibleCandidates.Add(Tuple.Create(regionPoints, regionIntensities));
```

Comment: Is this WPF or Winforms?

Comment: Please include the code you're using to populate the ListBox now.

Comment: This question can use a lot of work. First, as Bradley says, you need to tell us what API you're using. The techniques are different in each. Second, is each ListBox item really a Tuple of two Lists? Or is a List of Tuple<Point, int>? In either case, what is the "item's index"?

Comment: It's a Tuple of two Lists. When I refer to Item's index, I am talking about index of each item within the ListBox. So for example item 1 in the ListBox has index 0, and item 2 in the ListBox has index 1, and so on.

Comment: Do you need to use Tuple? creating a model for the listitem and using the listbox DisplayMember would be a far easier solution

Comment: Yes sa_ddam213 you are correct. I will need to create a listitem model to represent my items. I never used ListBox before, so this is the first time I came across this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found how to do this now.
It's done through ListControl.DisplayMember Property.

The reason it was displaying (System.Collection.Generic.List`1[System.Drawing.Point].Systen,Collection...) is because of this:

"If the specified property does not exist on the object or the value of DisplayMember is an empty string (""), the results of the object's ToString method are displayed instead."

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx

Code I used:

```
class Region
{
    private int myIndex;
    private List<Point> regionCoordinates;
    private List<int> regionIntensitiesDistinct;

    public Region(List<Point> regionCoordinates, List<int> regionIntensities, int index)
    {
        this.regionCoordinates = regionCoordinates;
        this.regionIntensitiesDistinct = regionIntensities.Distinct().ToList();
        this.myIndex = index;
    }

    public string MyDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return "Region-" + myIndex;
        }
    }

    public List<Point> getRegionCoordinates()
    {
        return regionCoordinates;
    }

    public List<int> getRegionIntensitiesDistinct()
    {
        return regionIntensitiesDistinct;
    }
}
```

Now this is how I populate my listBox:

```
List<Region> possibleCandidates = new List<Region>();

//using loop I add all the regions:
possibleCandidates.Add(new Region(regionPoints, regionIntensities, possibleCandidates.Count));

//after possibleCandidates are populated I pass them to the listBox for display
listBoxPossibleCandidates.DataSource = possibleCandidates;
listBoxPossibleCandidates.DisplayMember = "MyDescription";
```

The listBox output is now:

```
* Region-0
* Region-1
* Region-2
* ...
```

Comment: to make this an answer, pleas include the code that you are using now!

Comment: TaW - on the basis that source links are not stable, and their urls can change I believe that you are correct. So I added a snippet of the code I used to solve my problem.